# Installable trigger onEdit in addon - Error - document not being used

Tags: events, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets, protected

The code included in this post is using an installable "On Edit" trigger in an **addon**. An error message is coming up in the console when I pass the id of the document as argument to `.forSpreadsheet(ssss)` in Google Apps Script:

> This Add-on is attempting to create a trigger on a document that it is not currently being used in.

It seems like the Add-on doesn't recognize the active sheet properly. Where should the functions be placed? `onInstall()`, `onOpen()`?

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {  
      var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditTrigger')
    .forSpreadsheet(ssss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}

function onEditTrigger(e){
    isSheetName('SheetName') && sendingEmailFunction(e);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the ID.

Currently:

```
var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
```

Should be:

```
var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

The parameter `ss` for `.forSpreadsheet(ss)` must be a spreadsheet object.  You are entering a string.  `getId()` returns a string.  Always look at the data types returned, and the data type required.

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetsheet)

Comment: Is the project bound to the spreadsheet, or a stand alone script?  If it's a stand alone script, and you are running the code from the "Run" button, there is no active spreadsheet.   You either need to run the code in test mode, or run the code from the published Add-on.  You can publish the Add-on as "unlisted" without going through the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```